# .Net Core 3.1 The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, client-certificates

I am requesting using X509Certificate2 (test.pfx file). Everything works properly and without problems locally. However, when I upload my project to the server, I get an API error.

**The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized.**

Local https, but the site works on the server http.

Does anyone know what the problem is and how I can solve it?

Comment: `Local https, but the site works on the server http.`SSL certificate is used with https,not http.